# variables on localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, variables, local-storage

Hi i'would like to ask how to store data in localStorage.

I've got three part on my form. Part no 1 is a place where i put how many hives etc. got one person, and js calculate how much person should pay. Second part is an output where result of calculation is showed.

Part number three is a part where I got summary, it show me sum of previous things from all users. In case of crash of pc, I'd like to remember this data e.g. :

Before crash let say that two people paid and summary is : 20 bees' families , amount of bee yards: 2.

after restart I need back my summary, I add new person and now I have in summary for e.g. 40, 3

from line 150 to 164 it calculate summary( i push values to arr and reduce it)

on line 169 I inject it to HTML document.

Next I added my variables of summary to localStorage, an created condition( if there's no child elements in my div inject my html code and variables)

Unfortunately when I close window and open again I have nothing in summary.

project :

````
```java script

let beesSumTotal = sumaRodzin.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }, 0);
  let hivesSumTotal = hivesTotal.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }, 0);
  let moenySumTotal = moenyTotal.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }, 0);
  
  let peopleSumTotal = peopleTotal.length;

  outPut_ileWplat.value = peopleSumTotal;
  
  outPut_two.innerHTML = `<p>Rodzin łącznie: <br> <span class="display-2">${beesSumTotal}</span></p> <p>Pasiek łącznie:<br> <span class="display-2"> ${hivesSumTotal}</p> <p>Wpłaciło osób:<br> <span class="display-2">${peopleSumTotal}</p> <p>Zebrano:<br><span class="display-1"> ${moenySumTotal}</span> zł <p> <p class="small">raport składek</b> / ${dataWystawienia} / ${czasWystawienia}`
  
  
    window.localStorage.setItem("howManyPeople",  JSON.stringify(peopleSumTotal));
    window.localStorage.setItem("howManyHives", JSON.stringify(hivesSumTotal));
    window.localStorage.setItem("howManyBees", JSON.stringify(beesSumTotal));
    window.localStorage.setItem("howMuchMoney", JSON.stringify(moenySumTotal ));
  

     
  if (outPut_two.children.length === 0) {

    outPut_two.innerHTML = `<p>Rodzin łącznie: <br> <span class="display-2">${window.localStorage.getItem('howManyBees')}</span></p> <p>Pasiek łącznie:<br> <span class="display-2"> ${window.localStorage.getItem("howManyHives")}</p> <p>Wpłaciło osób:<br> <span class="display-2">${window.localStorage.getItem("howManyPeople")}</p> <p>Zebrano:<br><span class="display-1"> ${window.localStorage.geItem("howMuchMoney")}</span> zł <p> <p class="small">raport składek</b> / ${dataWystawienia} / ${czasWystawienia}
```
````

[screen of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyRAI.jpg)

https://jsfiddle.net/t4w75x0c/

Comment: Your code above never reads the localStorage. Your JSFiddle does not seem to use localStorage at all.

Comment: so how to place it to localStorage  ? And how to get it when  I refresh page or close the window and run one more time ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `localStorage.setItem`, you also have to use `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve the values. A simplified example:

SAVE

```
 localStorage.setItem("howManyPeople",  JSON.stringify(peopleSumTotal));
```

LOAD

```
 outPut_two.innerHTML = "total: 0"

 let stored = localStorage.getItem("howManyPeople");
 if(stored) {
     let peopleSumTotal = JSON.parse(stored);
     outPut_two.innerHTML = "total: " + peopleSumTotal
 }
```